# Calculate Sum of Column in SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I need to calculate Sum value of a Column.For that I am using the following query.But the app is crashed when I click a button to calculate.

```
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM " + (DbHelper.CART_TOTAL) + " FROM " + DbHelper.CART_TABLE, null);
if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
       Log.e("Net Total", cur.getInt(0) + "");
       return cur.getInt(0);
         }
        return 0;
```

**Logcat error:**

```
      android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
     no such column: SUM (code 1): , 
while compiling: SELECT SUM cart_total FROM cart_table
                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
                                                               at com.insideglobe.restaurant.Db.DbUtil.calculateNetTotal(DbUtil.java:276)
                                                               at com.insideglobe.restaurant.Adapter.MyCartAdapter$1.UpdateCart(MyCartAdapter.java:104)
                                                               at com.insideglobe.restaurant.Adapter.MyCartAdapter$1.onClick(MyCartAdapter.java:91)
                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16987)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
```

Comment: Would you like to file a bugreport as well?

Comment: Better read a tutorial how to write sum query http://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/functions/sum.php

Comment: Please make sure your query is correct, try ``Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT Sum (" + (DbHelper.CART_TOTAL) + ")  FROM " + DbHelper.CART_TABLE, null);``

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Correct way

```
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(" + DbHelper.CART_TOTAL + ") as Total FROM " + DbHelper.CART_TABLE, null);

 if (cur.moveToFirst()) {

 int total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Total"));// get final total
```

Comment: Quick Explanation: `Sum()` is a SQL function.

Comment: if Sum is possible without a RawQuery?

Answer (score 5):

You are missing **Round Braces**. Your query should be.

```
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(" + (DbHelper.CART_TOTAL) + ") FROM " + DbHelper.CART_TABLE, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Sample calculate SUM Value
    public int getSumValue(){
        int sum=0;
        database=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String sumQuery=String.format("SELECT SUM(%s) as Total FROM %s",dbHelper.VALUE,dbHelper.TABLE_NAME);
        Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery(sumQuery,null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
            sum= cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Total"));
        return sum;
    }
```

Note that: database is **SQLiteDatabase**, dbHelper is **DatabaseHelper** class (you create it and set name DatabaseHelper), dbHelper.VALUE is column name, dbHelper.TABLE_NAME is table name.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @MD in detail :

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(" + DBHelper.COST + ") as Total FROM " + DBHelper.EXPENSE_TABLE, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Total"));
        return total;
    }
```

- DBHelper: some Database Helper Class
- DBHelper.COST : Name of column for which cost is calculated
- EXPENSE_TABLE : name of the table