# Add get sum of single column in core data with One to Many Relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, one-to-many

Guys a quick question I'm a newbie to core data, I have two entities with one to many relationship as shown below.

[One to Many in Editor Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od4BL.png)

So I have a column named "item_total" in both the entities, I need to get the sum of the item_total column in Parent entity + Sum of the item_total column in child entity.

Lets say
[Table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QJsA.png)

so this both has one to many relationship, I need to get the sum as 120.

Comment: @Ganesh Kumar take a look at this site https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36279878/calculate-sum-of-column-in-sqlite-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single instance of `Cart`, you can get the total of all of its `item_total` values with something like

```
let cartTotal = cart.item_total + (cart.value(forKeyPath: "addON.@sum.item_total") as! Int32)
```

If you have an array of `Cart` you can get the total of the above for all `Cart` instances with something like

```
let overallTtotal = carts.reduce(0, { (previousResult, cart) -> Int32 in
    return previousResult +  cart.item_total + (cart.value(forKeyPath: "addON.@sum.item_total") as! Int32)
})
```