# SQLite SUM get value 0

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sum

I want get value from sqltie function SUM but i got value 0.

I am tired some example like this [Calculate Sum of Column in SQLite Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36279878/calculate-sum-of-column-in-sqlite-android) .but I didn't get 0 value.
This is my code

```
private static final String TABLE_REPORT                = "MST_REPORT";
private static final String FIELD_ID_REPORT             = "ID_REPORT";
private static final String FIELD_REPORT_Dollar         = "REPORT_Dollar";
private static final String FIELD_REPORT_QTY            = "REPORT_QTY";

   //CREATE REPORT TABLE
    String CREATE_REPORT = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_REPORT + "("
            + FIELD_ID_REPORT + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + FIELD_REPORT_Dollar + " INTEGER, "
            + FIELD_REPORT_QTY+ " INTEGER "+ ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_REPORT);

    //REPORT
    //ADD REPORT
    public void addReport(MstReport Report) {
    SQLiteDatabase db       = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values    = new ContentValues();
    values.put(FIELD_ID_REPORT, Report.getIdReport());
    values.put(FIELD_REPORT_Dollar, Report.getReportDollar());
    values.put(FIELD_REPORT_QTY, Report.getReportQty());
    db.insert(TABLE_REPORT, null, values);
}

    //GET ALL REPORT
    public List<MstReport> getAllReport() {
    List<MstReport> ListReport    = new ArrayList<MstReport>();
    String selectQuery                  = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_REPORT;
    SQLiteDatabase db                   = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor                       = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            MstReport Data = new MstReport();
            Data.setIdReport(cursor.getString(0));
            Data.setReportDollar(cursor.getInt(1));
            Data.setReportQty(cursor.getInt(2));
            ListReport.add(Data);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return ListReport;
}
```

when I call getAllReport function there are value. but when I call function SUM I got value 0.
this is the function (getReportUSD())..

```
public List<MstReport> getReportUSD() {
    List<MstReport> ListReportSUMD = new ArrayList<MstReport>();
    String selectQuery             = "SELECT SUM (" +FIELD_REPORT_Dollar+ ")as TotalUSD FROM " + TABLE_REPORT;
    SQLiteDatabase db              = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor                  = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            MstReport Data = new MstReport();
             Data.setReportRp(cursor.getColumnIndex("TotalUSD");
            ListReportSUMD.add(Data);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return ListReportSUMD;
}
```

When I debug the result is SUM value is 0.
Sorry I am newbiew developer. hope you can help me. Thank you :)

Comment: You basically told us the query isn't working, without giving any additional information.  Have you tried debugging your Android code to see what is happening?

Comment: I tried debuging but the result is 0

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Data.setReportRp(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("TotalUSD")));
```

instead of

```
Data.setReportRp(cursor.getColumnIndex("TotalUSD");
```

Currently passing column index to `setReportRp` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns the sum of a column in the table, which is only 1 row with 1 column with index 0.
You don't even need a loop:

```
public List<MstReport> getReportUSD() {
    List<MstReport> ListReportSUMD = new ArrayList<MstReport>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT SUM (" + FIELD_REPORT_Dollar + ")as TotalUSD FROM " + TABLE_REPORT;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        MstReport Data = new MstReport();
        Data.setReportRp(cursor.getInt(0));
        ListReportSUMD.add(Data);
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return ListReportSUMD;
}
```

Also since what you want as result is just an integer, your method could return an integer and not a list (unless you need the value stored as a single item in a list).
So maybe you can rewrite it like this:

```
public int getReportUSD() {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT SUM (" + FIELD_REPORT_Dollar + ")as TotalUSD FROM " + TABLE_REPORT;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    int result = 0;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        result = cursor.getInt(0);
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return result;
}
```